# Azure AD Custom Role - Permissions - Data Actions not returned in REST API - Role Definitions - Get

Tags: azure, api, rest, azure-active-directory

I am exploring **Azure REST API**s to collect some information for *Role Assignments*. I created a *Custom Role* and added permissions to it. When permissions are being added to storage accounts, there are two types of actions - *Actions* and *Data Actions*.

When I tried to retrieve the Role Definition through Role Definitions - Get API explained here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roledefinitions/get

It only returns *Actions* and not *Data Actions*.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataActions` are still in preview.

To work with `DataActions` in the REST API, please set the api-version to `2018-01-01-preview`.